# Receiving access denied error from Visual Studio when trying to change target framework

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

The error reads,

> TargetFrameworkMoniker: An error occurred saving the project file
>   'yadayada.csproj'. Access is denied.

I'm trying to switch from .net 3.5 to .net 4.0 or higher.

The project is hooked into TFS in Visual Studio 2010 (also tried VS 2013, same error). I'm in a VM environment.

Any clues about this error? Google returns very little information. It seems like I have proper access to the file, but how is VS accessing it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It sounds like either:

1)The file has been marked read only.  Check this by viewing the properties of the csproj.

Or

2)Your user does not has sufficient permissions to change the file - check security on the csproj.

Comment: Thanks- #1 got it. Not sure how this happened. I unchecked read only and was then able to change the target framework.

Comment: Its odd, as TFS should usually clear the read only flag when the file is checked out, so you might also want to check the file is checked out so you can check it back in to commit any changes you make.

Comment: I've had similar issue and it seems that unless you open all of your projects or "Check-out for Edit", in your solution, the conversion will basically fail as the Visual Studio is also changing some other files. Reason why I say this is because I had to make non-TFS local copy of my solution and un-ticked `Read-Only` for all the items and it worked without a single error! Hope this will help others when they read this.

Comment: Neither (1) nor (2)...I was an administrator, and i checked if the file was read only...it wasn't. My workaround was to delete the original file, then save the new file again. Thought I might put that out there for others who had that same problem

Answer (score 17):

I have found that if you get the error, hit save, close visual studio and reopen the project you will find that 86.5% of the time the setting was changed.

Comment: My test results verify this solution works round 78.3% of the time.  It must be because I'm on Window 10

Comment: Can confirm. Test results yield an 81.723% success rate with Cortana disabled.

Answer (score 3):

Try running the Visual Studio in administrator mode and also check if your project folder is set to read only.

Comment: Running Visual Studio in administrator mode is what worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error in my environment, which is straight VS 2013 Pro: no TFS and no VM. Unsetting the read-only box only changed the dialog display because reinvoking the dialog still showed read-only. I thought I changed the ownership of the project file to me by virtue of changing the ownership in a higher level directory and checking "Replace all child object permission entries **with inheritable permission entries from this object**." Of course the project file and everything else had inheritance turned off. Once that was corrected I was able to save things without being Administrator.

Comment: I think this is close to the real issue! I have had privilege problems in Win11 and later versions of VS and also with Android studio. This solution worked (rebooting also, but this solution eliminated the issue).

Answer (score 2):

Deleting everything in bin file of the starting project did it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error and it ended up being the app.config file, as well, that was write-protected.  Changing the target framework not only changed

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

in the .csproj file but also changed the project's app.config:

```
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
```

(I wanted to add this as a comment to pixelmeow's Jun 27 answer, but StackOverflow policy prevents me from doing so until I have enough reputation points.  I did vote for him/her, though!)

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this error message in my Visual Studio 2022 Solution **after updating to Version 17.1.5**. I managed it to run again by closing VS and **deleting/renaming the bin and obj folder**. Restarting VS and the debug session ran without trouble.

Comment: This was my solution. Close VS, Delete bin folder, Open VS (not as admin) - project runs fine. Had installed an update to VS (probably thats why)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error and it ended up being the app.config file that was write-protected. Once I cleared the read-only property, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error in visual studio 2010 because of my start action setting. Each time I would hit debug, I think the browser window was trying to launch too fast (this is an ASP.NET MVC 4 with intranet settings project).. and I would randomly, sometimes consistently get access denied. So I changed the start action to: "Don't open a page. Wait for a request from external application."

And this seemed to fix the issue. You will just have to access the web application manually rather than VS launching the browser for you. You can click on the running server icon (bottom right of taskbar) and access the link from there if you don't remember it or your browser didn't store it as a history url for whatever reason.