# Debug in Visual Studio 2017 gives access denied

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017

I have installed Visual Studio on Windows server 2012 and now I'm trying to debug an existing project. This gives me 'Error while trying to run project - access denied'
I have now problems running the project without debugging.

I have restarted Studio and no files are read-only

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Receiving access denied error from Visual Studio when trying to change target framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22509303/receiving-access-denied-error-from-visual-studio-when-trying-to-change-target-fr)

Comment: Run Visual Studio with admin permissions.  Did you spend any time Googling for this before you posted here?

Comment: Please create a new project to check whether it also has the same problem. And you also could try create a new project and copy the original project files into the new project and debug it again.

Comment: I have tried to start Studio as admin - no difference

Comment: I have tried to create a blank solution - this also gives 'access denied'. Looks like a problem with the installation of Studio - like to hear if there are any other solution than to try and re-install Studio ?

Comment: @PaulSorensen Please use ProcessMonitor(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to trace which file is access denied. In addition, please check this document which has similar problem. You could try the workaround in this link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/821255/error-while-trying-to-run-project-error-message-occurs-when-you-debug

Comment: It's the executable itself that gives the access denied. I have tried to create a new console app and get this when I compile it

System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\projects\EDS\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\ConsoleApp1.runtimeconfig.json' is denied.

I don't know if this is related

Comment: @PaulSorensen According to the denied path, your project is stored in C: drive. Please try copy your project to other driver, such as D:, to check whether it still be denied. And also please check the permission for the folder where the project stored, make sure it has all read/write permission.

Comment: I have tried to create a new console app on d: - it gives Unable to start program 'c:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe'

Comment: I have tried to install Visual studio 2017 on an new windows 2012 server and the create a basic consoleapp - I get Unable to start program 'c:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe - access denied

Also tried to start studio as an admin - same problem

I can start the program in studio without the debugger but not with the debugger

Comment: Found the solution

enable 'use managed compatibility mode' in the debugging>general section of VS2017 options.

found here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/49763/access-denied-when-attempting-to-run-under-the-deb.html

Comment: @Paul Sorensen, Glad to know that you have resolved this issue, if possible, please add your solution as the answer(not as a comment), so you could mark and close this case, and it would help other community members who get the same issue find the answer easily. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution enable 'use managed compatibility mode' in the debugging>general section of VS2017 options. found here:https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/49763/access-denied-when-attempting-to-run-under-the-deb.html

Comment: As of VS 2022 this option appears to have been removed.

Answer (score 3):

What fixed it for me (Running VS2019 + Win10) was adding my source folder to the exclusion from Windows Defender Threat Protection.

Comment: As long as your organisation does not use Group Policy to prevent you modifying the exclusion list :D :(

Answer (score 1):

Access Denied errors can occur if a file has an unresolved lock on it. This can happen whether or not your file, typically the executable that you just compiled, is read-only or not.

The easiest way to clear a lock like that is to reboot your system. Or if you're unwilling to reboot or you just want to make one file available again, you could use a tool such as [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to find the process that is using the file, and either close the program or kill that process.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution was to DISABLE 'use managed compatibility mode' in the debugging>general section of VS2019 options.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Registry Editor

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"EnableLinkedConnections"=dword:00000001
```

This will solve the problem