# Unable to start program VS2015 | Access denied | system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, runtime-error, vtk

I am trying to configure VTK with VS 2015 on win10 x64  . I downloaded VTK-8.1.0 source, created VS2015 project with cmake and build it with Visual Studio IDE. To test, I downloaded the [sphere visualization code](https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Cxx/GeometricObjects/Sphere/) and created a VS2015 project with cmake and build it with VS2015 IDE. Everything is successfull. I run the .exe created from vtkproject/build/debug/.exe and I get the output as expected. Its displays a sphere. But when I run the program from the IDE, it gives runtime error as shown below:
[image: build output]
[image]

I also tried using the pre-built VTK-7.0 binaries which were a part of PCL pre-built x64 binaries for VS2015 from [this blog](http://unanancyowen.com/en/pcl18/) and tested the above mentioned sphere visualization program. Build seems to work and again I get the expected output from running the .exe created in vtkproject/build/debug/.exe but I get another runtime error when trying to run program from VS IDE as shown below:

[image].

I saw a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46520555/debug-in-visual-studio-2017-gives-access-denied) but the accepted answer doesn't work for me.

Kindly help me regarding this issue.

Comment: Your cwd (current working directory) is probably set wrong when running from the IDE.

Comment: Thanks @JesperJuhl . You nudged me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem thanks to Jesper Juhl hint. CWD was correct but it was none the less a directory path problem.

- The first error occurred because in  project
  properties->configuration manager, the build option against ALL_Build
  was unchecked.
- The second error occurred because in ALL_BUILD project properties-> configuration properties->Debugging->Command was set to x64/Debug/ALL_BUILD. It should be set to Debug/Sphere.exe  (Debug in the solution folder, not in x64)